# what is the standard way to design a high throughput spring based web serivce with Async in mind

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous

I have a requirement to design spring-boot based webservice with @Async tags. 
if the data return from server takes huge time how can i divide my webservice in multiple end points so that client does not have to wait for response from server.

i hv tried using three end points. 
1. localhost:8080/start -> client will send request for data. (returs a uuid of requestnumber).
2. localhost:8080/checkprogress -> check for progress if data is ready at server.
3. localhost:8080/done/requestId -> return the data list

```
@ResponseBody
    @GetMapping(value = "/start")
    public ResponseEntity<String> start() {
        String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        LOG.info("jobName" + requestId);

        Job job = new Job("jobName" + requestId);

        requestQueue.put(requestId.toString(), job);
        service.submitWork(job);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(requestId, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/progress/{requestId}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> fetchStatus(@PathVariable("requestId") String requestId) {
        Job job = requestQueue.get(requestId);
        if (job == null) {

            return new ResponseEntity<String>("RequestId is either invalid or already served. requestId:" + requestId,
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if (job.getState() == State.RUNNING || job.getState() == State.NEW)
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        if (job.getState() == State.DONE)
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);

        return null;

    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/done/{requestId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> done(@PathVariable("requestId") String requestId) {
        LOG.info("removing requestId:" + requestId);

        Job job = requestQueue.get(requestId);
        if (job == null) {

            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("RequestId is either invalid or already served. requestId:" + requestId,
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

//        ResponseEntity<Object> response = new ResponseEntity<Object>(job.getList(),
//                createHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), HttpStatus.OK);
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = new ResponseEntity<Object>(job.getListOfSecurities(),
                createHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE), HttpStatus.OK);

        requestQueue.remove(requestId);
        return response;
    }
```

is there a better way of doing above thing in a Standard way in spring-boot java8 application please?

Comment: That's more or less how you do it. Take care of the details like what happens when the server restarts when jobs are in progress and what you do when a client submits jobs and never comes back or a malicious client hits you with a million jobs in a few seconds.

Comment: is there a way to use SSEEmitter to achive above?